# Bash: Spliting string based on some delimiter and storing each in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

```
113050050/CS101/mysql_java.pdf
```

the above is my string, which is stored in a variable 'line'

```
line="113050050/CS101/mysql_java.pdf"
```

Now I want to split `$line` based on delimiter `/` and store each single part in a variable

```
var1=113050050
var2=CS101
var3=mysql_java.pdf
```

Comment: Wouldn't an array be better than separate variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ IFS=/ read var1 var2 var3 <<< "$line"
```

Results

```
$ echo $var1
113050050

$ echo $var2
CS101

$ echo $var3
mysql_java.pdf
```

Comment: +1 If you don't know how many components are in `$line` beforehand, you can use `IFS=/ read -a dirs <<< "$line"` to put the result in an array.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
line="113050050/CS101/mysql_java.pdf"
var=(${line//\// })
var1=${var[0]}
var2=${var[1]}
var3=${var[2]}
```

as @chepner points out this will fail if spaces exist in the `$line` variable, a perhaps more bullet-proof solution is to use the `IFS` variable:

```
line="113050050/CS101/mysql_java.pdf" O="$IFS" IFS='/' var=($line) IFS="$O"
```

Comment: This will fail when `line` contains spaces as well. You aren't splitting on `/`; you're turning them into spaces, then splitting on *all* spaces, not just the ones that replaced '/'.